# Async function in new thread

Tags: rust

I am trying to call an async function in a new thread.

```
async fn init(){
    println!("Running");
}

fn load(){
    thread::spawn(init);

    //Or async closure
    thread::spawn(async|| {
        init().await;
    });
}
```

But I can't achieve it. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: `std::thread` is not an executor for `Future` tasks. You'll need an executor to run futures or you need to poll it manually on different threads(which can be considered as implementing executor ^^).

Comment: Please check this simple example: https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/blob/master/examples/functional/src/main.rs, it uses `block_on` which blocks the enclosing thread while polling future. You can also check runtime feature in tokio crate.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Thank you!